# Graphql resolver isn't returning any data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, graphql, apollo

I have a resolver set up that queries mock db file (a json).

```
Query: {
        users: (_, filters, { dataSources }) => {
            console.log(dataSources.userAPI.getAllUsers(filters))
            return dataSources.userAPI.getAllUsers(filters);
        }
}
```

userAPI.getALlUsers is below. First I want to filter the list of users. Then for each filtered user, I want to add more fields to it before return the mapped users

```
function getAllUsers(args) {
    const { targetId, skip, limit } = args;

    const filteredUsers = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const users = db.users.filter(u => {
            if (u.apps[targetId]) return u;
        });
        if (users.length === 0) return reject();
        else return resolve(users);
    });

    filteredUsers.then((users, err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            const mappedUsers = users.map(u => {
                const withReturnFields = {
                    email: u.email,
                    fullname: u.fullname
                };
                return withReturnFields;
            });
            return mappedUsers.slice(skip, skip + limit);
        }
    });
}
```

I think my promise isn't working as expected. Any insights? My schemas are all set up correctly. I tried console logging

Comment: Closing this as a dupe. As Nazar showed, you need to return the Promise inside the resolver. If you're unable to resolve the other error you're seeing, feel free to open a new question with the full error message and your relevant Apollo Server config.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAllUsers` function returns `undefined`. When resolver return `undefined` it means that the object could not be found, you should return a promise instead.

```
return filteredUsers.then((users, err) => {
```

Comment: I added return and I got this error :
    ```{"message": "Abstract type User must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.users with value { email: \"john.doe@test.com\", fullname: \"Full Name1\" }, received \"undefined\". Either the User type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."}```

why is it still receiving undefined? Below is my schemas: 

```
users(
 targetId: ID
 skip: Int # for pagination
 limit: Int # for pagination
): [User!]!

interface User {
  email: String!
  fullname: String!
}

Comment: That is unrelated to your original issue. You've defined the User type as either a union or interface. That means you must also provide either a `resolveType` function for User, or a `isTypeOf` function for each type User could be. You're either missing `resolveType` entirely or you did not implement it correctly.